# Why does basic_istream_view inherit view_interface?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

[`basic_istream_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.istream.view) is a simple `input_range` in C++20 and has only one `begin()` and `end()` function:

```
template<movable Val, class CharT, class Traits>
  requires default_­initializable<Val> &&
           stream-extractable<Val, CharT, Traits>
class basic_istream_view : public view_interface<
                                    basic_istream_view<Val, CharT, Traits>> { 
 public:
  constexpr iterator begin();
  constexpr default_sentinel_t end() const noexcept;
};
```

It inherits `view_interface` which is defined in [[view.interface]](https://eel.is/c++draft/view.interface) as:

```
template<class D>
class view_interface {
 public:
  constexpr bool empty() requires forward_­range<D>;

  constexpr explicit operator bool()
    requires requires { ranges::empty(derived()); };

  constexpr auto data() requires contiguous_­iterator<iterator_t<D>>;

  constexpr auto size() requires forward_­range<D>;

  constexpr decltype(auto) front() requires forward_­range<D>;
  constexpr decltype(auto) back() requires bidirectional_­range<D>;

  template<random_­access_­range R = D>
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](range_difference_t<R> n);
};
```

You can see that almost all member functions of `view_interface` require `D` to be `forward_range`, while `operator bool()` requires `ranges::empty(derived())` to be well-formed, which also requires `D` to be `forward_range`.

It seems that the only purpose of `basic_istream_view` inheriting `view_interface` is to model a [`view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.view) since `view` requires `view_base` or `view_interface` to be inherited.

But if you want to make `basic_istream_view` a view, why not just inherit it directly from `view_base`? I can't see any benefit from inheriting `view_interface` except for the cost of template instantiation.

So, why does `basic_istream_view` inherit the `view_interface` instead of `view_base`? Does it have historical reasons?

Comment: To me it looks like it's providing suitable implementations for member functions via CRTP. Also note DR [LWG 3549](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3549): "_`view_interface` was required to be derived from `view_base`,
which sometimes required multiple `view_base` subobjects in a view._". This inheritance is now removed from the standard

Comment: "*What are the considerations behind this?*" I don't really understand your question. It's a view. Views ought to inherit from `view_interface`. What more "considerations" do you need?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas.  I mean "*why does the basic_istream_view inherit the view_interface instead of view_base?*"

Comment: And my question to you is... why *shouldn't* it? That is, just because the member functions aren't available doesn't mean that it's inappropriate to inherit from it.

Comment: @NicolBolas. I understand what you mean. In my opinion, simply inheriting `view_base` seems to be a better choice, but this may just be my one-sided word, thank you for your enlightenment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the member functions of `view_interface` today all need forward ranges doesn't mean that we will never add member functions in the future that can work on input ranges too.

Also, why not?